# changing the background of the grid in the pie chart from jqPlot

Tags: jquery, plugins, background, jqplot, pie-chart

I want to use this pie chart:
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

but for the grid I want a transparent background. According to the options: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html I can change the colour but they don't say anything about the transparency, any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

For what i understood i have prepared this example for you:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFVXv/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [
        ['Heavy Industry', 12],
        ['Retail', 9],
        ['Light Industry', 14],
        ['Out of home', 16],
        ['Commuting', 7],
        ['Orientation', 9]
    ];
    var plot2 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                // Turn off filling of slices.
                fill: false,
                showDataLabels: true,
                // Add a margin to seperate the slices.
                sliceMargin: 0,
                // stroke the slices with a little thicker line.
                lineWidth: 0,
                shadowOffset: 0,
                shadowAlpha: 0
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e'
        }
    });
});
```